# How to fetch all basic information of facebook user(not friend) in android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have to fetch name, id, gender, age location, interest, birthday of facebook user which is not in my friend list.

Currently i am getting only name, id and gender of the user. Can anybody tell me how can i access other parameter...??

My code is

```
Request req = new Request(session, facebookID, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response facebookUserResponse) {

                System.out.println("Facebook User Response is: "+ facebookUserResponse);

                GraphObject facebookUserResponseGraphObject = facebookUserResponse.getGraphObject();
                JSONObject facebookUserResponseJSONObject = facebookUserResponseGraphObject.getInnerJSONObject();


                String gender = null;
                String birthday = null;
                String timezone = null;
                String hometown = null;
                String location = null;
                String age_range_min = null;
                String age_range_max = null;


                try{
                    gender = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getString("gender");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    gender = null;
                }

                try{
                    birthday = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getString("birthday");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    birthday = null;
                }

                try{
                    timezone = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getString("timezone");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    timezone = null;
                }

                try{
                    hometown = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getJSONObject("hometown").getString("name");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    hometown = null;
                }

                try{
                    location = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    location = null;
                }

                try{
                    age_range_min = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getJSONObject("age_range").getString("min");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    age_range_min = null;
                }

                try{
                    age_range_max = facebookUserResponseJSONObject.getJSONObject("age_range").getString("max");
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    age_range_max = null;
                }


        }
    });

        Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

all columns available in user table is listed.

Comment: getting  only gender value other parameter getting null

Comment: to access some of the fields you need to add permission first.
check this one. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

Comment: my first doubt is can i access all info of a unknown facebook user..??

Comment: I guess it is possible. I haven't tried it yet though. can you post your code?

Comment: one more thing @blitzen12 i have to fetch user info from my application(android) there are two option available there first one is  from graph api another is from application

Comment: to access user location you need "user_location" as permissions.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/fetch-user-data/  also accessing user info like location.